# Is it good idea to learn English and German simultaneously?

Tags: learning-methods

I'm learning English but considering to improve my German as well.

My native language is Ukrainian. I know both languages on the same basic level.

Is it good idea to learn English and German simultaneously? Are there any particular techniques or advices?

Comment: I can't answer this question, but people who may be able to answer it may want to know what your native language is. Is it another West Germanic language, such as Dutch, or a language which is more distantly related to German and English, such as Russian?

Comment: @fi12, thanks a lot, appreciate it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Knowing English can be a lot of help when trying to learn German because both languages share a lot of related or similar vocabulary and grammatical structures. For example, I can guess that as a native speaker of Ukrainian some concepts in these languages, such as articles, may be hard for you to master. Knowing how to use articles in English would help you learn how to use them in German (though their usage in English in German is not the same, of course).

However, if your level in both languages is really similar, I would hesitate about learning two quite closely related languages because of possible interference. In short: you have to be aware that you will probably get aspects of both languages mixed up.

The perfect solution of course would be to "level up" your English before getting serious with German, where the interference would be more helpful. If that is not possible, a handful of hints:

- Visually differentiate your learning materials. Even minor things such as differently coloured paper or pen for each of the languages can help.
- If you are learning with a teacher, make them aware that you are attempting both languages. They may be able to help you, or at least will know where your potential mistakes come from.
- Despite the problems, **make use of the similarities!** Look for analogies in word stems, note down true and false friends.

Answer (score 1):

[in Ukrainian]:

По-перше, я пропоную вам використовувати російський "**Яндекс**" перекладач "**Периводцик**" знайдено в [**translate.yandex.ru**] в якості інструменту дослідження для будь-другий чи третій мову ви виберете для вивчення.

І це, як мовиться, ви б краще порадили концентрат навчальних годин на вивчення англійської мови, як англійська (або Континентальний або Північно-американському діалекті) є міжнародною мовою у використанні і стане в нагоді скрізь, в той час як німецька мова має тільки обмежений діапазон корисності, тобто Північної Європи.

Не тільки обмеженість німецької мови буде розглядатися для вас, але ваша рідна мова (українська) - це слов'янська мова, її граматику і порядок слів зовсім трохи відрізняється від німецького.

Більш стабільний української і німецької мов також зовсім трохи відрізняється від англійської мови, адже англійська мова-поліглот "лінгва Франка" колекція словників і граматик латинської, англо-саксонської, Фризької, датською, голландською, Фламандської, різних німецьких "Платт" діалекти, і французький.

Тоді я пропоную свої пріоритети слід вивчати англійську мову, першим розмовною англійською, а потім більш просунуті академічної англійської, а також провести вивчення німецька на більш пізній термін.

[English translation]:

First off, I'd suggest you use the Russian "**Yandex**" translator "**Периводцик**" found at [**translate.yandex.ru**] as a study tool for whatever second or third language you choose to study.

And that being said, you would be best advised to concentrate your study hours on learning the English language, as English (either the Continental or North American dialect) is an international language in use and useful everywhere, whereas the German language has only a limited range of usefulness, i.e. northern Europe.

Not only should the limitations of the German language be a consideration for you, but your native language (Ukrainian) is a Slavic language; its grammar and word order are quite a bit different from German.

The more stable Ukrainian and the German languages are also quite a bit different from the English language, as English is a polyglot 'lingua franca' collection of the vocabularies and grammars of Latin, Anglo-Saxon, Frisian, Danish, Dutch, Flemish, various German "platt" dialects, and French.

So then my suggestion is that your priorities should be to study English -- first conversational English and then more advanced academic English -- and hold your study of German for a later date.

Comment: I think my suggestion is reinforced by the omission of the English definite article "a" at the beginning of user Kovalsky's  title, i.e.,  "Is it good idea...", a characteristic of Russian, Bulgarian, Ukrainian, and I suppose other Slavic languages learned and taught early on by Latin-speaking Christian monks.